# Oracle WHERE Multiple Columns IN Subquery "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator"

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle, where-in

I want to select from table where multiple columns selected from sub query using **WHERE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) IN (SUB QUERY)**

```
    SELECT * FROM ORDER_DETAIL
    WHERE (ORDER_ID, ACTION_SEQUENCE, DETAIL_SEQUENCE)
    IN (
        SELECT ORDER_ID, ACTION_SEQUENCE, DETAIL_SEQUENCE
        FROM ORDER_DETAIL
        WHERE ORDER_ID=314239027
    );
```

But an exception raises

**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator**

Comment: This query runs without error in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=860682bdaad331dbcf7357295368043e)

Comment: The syntax is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd91474de4a09aa83b0a02b252b30bb2 there must be something else in the way you run it or the tool you are using. What tool do you use to run that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The exception says "cx_Oracle" so I'm guessing python and the `cx_Oracle` module and have updated the tags to reflect this as the answer may revolve around the behaviour supported by that module rather than the allowed syntax for the database.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Oracle is concerned, that's OK. But, the query itself doesn't have much sense. It is equal to (with the help of my friends)

```
select *
from order_detail
where order_id = 314239027
  and action_sequence is not null     -- if those columns ...
  and detail_sequence is not null     -- ... can contain nulls
```

so I suggest you use it instead.

Comment: @MT0: as my last sentence says, it looks quite stupid. I don't know whether anyone writes queries this way. But, I don't know how **cx_Oracle.DatabaseError** works. Just as I (and GMB and a_horse_with_no_name and - I belive - you and others) said & know, query the OP posted is OK as far as Oracle is concerned. **Maybe** that "cx_Oracle" thing (what is it? Python?) has its own rules which find such queries invalid. As I said: I'd write it as my first query, it makes most sense (to me). My second query is (again & still) *stupid*, but - maybe it'll make cx_Oracle "believe" it is OK.

Comment: @MT0: ah, yes - exactly what you posted as a comment: "the answer may revolve around the behaviour supported by that module rather than the allowed syntax for the database". I was trying to "revolve the behaviour".

Comment: This querey my return rows where the order_id, action_sequence  and detail_sequence  values are found on different rows. Not the same as OP is trying to do.

Comment: Ah! Finally got it! Thanks, @jarlh & MT0. Sure, what I wrote really **is** stupid. Will remove it. Sorry.

Comment: `where order_id = 314239027 and ACTION_SEQUENCE is not null and DETAIL_SEQUENCE is not null`, if the columns can contain null values.